# Wrong HBM mappings when using a mapped superclass in an inheritance graph for ColdFusion 9.0.1 Hotfix 2

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, hibernate-mapping, coldfusion-9

Let's say I have an inheritance graph where the base class extends a mapped superclass:

```
component name="Entity" mappedSuperClass="true"
{
    property name="CreatedOn";
}

component name="Pet" extends="Entity" table="Pet" discriminatorcolumn="pet_type"
{
    property name="PetId" fieldtype="id" generator="native";
    property name="Name";
}

component name="Dog" extends="Pet" table="Pet" discriminatorvalue="Dog"
{
    property name="FavoriteFood";
}

component name="Cat" extends="Pet" table="Pet" discriminatorvalue="Cat"
{
    property name="FavoriteSleepingSpot";
}
```

In this case, I have a `Pet` base class with two subclasses, `Dog` and `Cat`. `Pet` also extends `Entity`, which provides some auditing properties.

In **ColdFusion 9.0.1** and **ColdFusion 9.0.1 Hotfix 1**, these components are mapped correctly. I verified it by dumping the HBM mappings. However, in **ColdFusion 9.0.1 HotFix 2**, the mappings are incorrect. For example, the `Cat` mapping should be:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <subclass discriminator-value="Cat"
        entity-name="Cat" extends="cfc:model.Pet"
        lazy="true" name="cfc:model.Cat">
        <property name="FavoriteSleepingSpot" type="string">
            <column name="FAVORITE_SLEEPING_SPOT"/>
        </property>
    </subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

But what actually gets generated is this:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <subclass discriminator-value="Cat"
        entity-name="Cat" extends="cfc:model.Pet"
        lazy="true" name="cfc:model.Cat">
        <property name="FavoriteSleepingSpot" type="string">
            <column name="FAVORITE_SLEEPING_SPOT"/>
        </property>
        <property name="CreatedOn" type="timestamp">
            <column name="CREATED_ON"/>
        </property>
    </subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

In other words, the subclass mapping is including the `CreatedOn` in the `Entity` class when it shouldn't be, and this understandably leads to the following error:

> Repeated column in mapping for entity: Cat column: CREATED_ON (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

**My question is**, is something wrong with the way my entities are declared? Or have I stumbled across a bug in **Hotfix 2**? If so, what would be the fix for it?

The workaround I'm currently using is to dump the HBM files and edit them manually to remove the duplicated property mapping. This is working fine, but I have to repeat this process every time the entities change. Unfortunately, we can't roll back to Hotfix 1 either because we need some of the fixes in Hotfix 2.

Comment: have you reported to http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html ?

Comment: Not yet, wanted to see if anybody had any ideas first.

Comment: maybe related to changes introduced in 83474 @ http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/918/cpsid_91836.html

Comment: Daniel:  did you ever file a bug for this?  I wonder if this still happens on CF10?

Comment: @Todd: I don't remember if I filed a bug fix for this. I think I did though. It may have been fixed in CF10, but I'm no longer working with ColdFusion so I can't verify.