# ColdFusion ORM mappedSuperClass .hbmxml has too many fields

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

When I run the code below, ColdFusion 9 (updated to latest) generates a wrong (imho) XML file for the billingaddress cfc. Namely, it includes the properties of base.cfc. Is this a bug, am I missing something, or is this expected behavior?

#### Application.cfc

```
component
{
  this.name = "ormtest";
  this.mappings["/model"] = expandPath( "./model" );
  this.datasource = "mingo";
  this.ormEnabled = true;
  this.ormSettings = {
    CFCLocation = "/model",
    dbcreate = "dropcreate",
    savemapping = true
  };

  function onRequestStart()
  {
    ormreload();    
  }
}
```

#### base.cfc

```
component mappedSuperClass = "true"
{
  property fieldType = "id"     name = "id" generator = "guid";
  property fieldType = "column" name = "deleted" ORMType = "boolean" default = "0" notnull = "true";
  property fieldType = "column" name = "sortorder" ORMType = "integer";
  property fieldType = "column" name = "label";
}
```

#### address.cfc

```
component extends = "model.base"
          persistent = "true"
          table="address"
          discriminatorColumn = "discriminator"
{
  property name = "address";
}
```

#### billingaddress.cfc

```
component extends = "model.address"
          persistent = "true"
          table="address"
          discriminatorValue = "billingaddress"
{}
```

#### billingaddress.hbmxml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <subclass discriminator-value="billingaddress"
        entity-name="billingaddress" extends="cfc:model.address"
        lazy="true" name="cfc:model.billingaddress">
        <property name="deleted" type="boolean">
            <column name="deleted" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="sortorder" type="integer">
            <column name="sortorder"/>
        </property>
        <property name="label" type="string">
            <column name="label"/>
        </property>
    </subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Any reason why you have dbcreate = "dropcreate" and savemapping = true? Also having a ormreload() in your onRequestStart() will cause your model to be rebuilt on every request. It's more normal to have it in your onApplicationStart().

Comment: Yes, the reason is, this is just a test setup to verify my sanity. On the live and dev environments we run with different settings (dbcreate="none" for live)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the behavior I would expect. Extending a component will cause the child to inherit the parent's properties. When you have multiple levels of inheritance, it will inherit all the way back up the chain.

After reading your comments, I looked into this a little further. As far as I can tell, the problem you're describing first showed up in [CF9 Cumulative Hot Fix 2](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/cumulative-hot-fix-2-coldfusion-1.html), probably (just guessing here) as a result of this bug fix:

> ColdFusion ORM does not maintain the column order correctly when the
>   CFC extends a base cfc with an attribute mappedSuperclass set to
>   true.

The bug referenced is #83474, which I can't seem to find on Adobe's bug tracker. It's mirrored on Elliot Sprehn's site, [here](http://www.elliottsprehn.com/cfbugs/bugs/83474).

I also found another question here on SO regarding the same problem: [Wrong HBM mappings when using a mapped superclass in an inheritance graph for ColdFusion 9.0.1 Hotfix 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972839/wrong-hbm-mappings-when-using-a-mapped-superclass-in-an-inheritance-graph-for-co). The workaround reported in that question is to manually edit the hbmxml files.

Long story short, it looks like a CF bug. I poked at it for about 20 minutes and was unable to find a workaround other than manually editing the hbmxml files to remove the extra properties from billingaddress.cfc.

Comment: Do you know how I should go about recreating this [strategy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WS027D3772-2E98-4d5b-8800-054A62EBF8D9.html#WSB268B0CB-17CB-4e28-B0D3-ED72DF166D8E) while using mappedSuperClass="true"? Because when I do it this way, hibernate returns a duplicate column error: `Repeated column in mapping for entity: billingaddress column: deleted (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")` Which makes sense. I'm curious why it would know that it needs to inherit the "id"-column but not the other columns.

Comment: It seems to be a bug with CF9, I've tested the same code in Railo 4.2 and there it works as expected.

Comment: In about an hour, I can give it a shot on CF11. I don't have any earlier versions installed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've accepted your answer and will go with manual hbmxml files, at least for now.

Comment: I found the [bugbase link](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3041728) to the bug, but it is marked as Fixed.

Comment: @Mingo Sorry, what I meant was that I believe the bug you're experiencing was likely introduced by the fix for 83474. I'm not sure if there's an open bug for your issue.